# Default Values from API in MUI Text field

Tags: reactjs, api, material-ui, textfield

I have a form that I built using material UI that I would like to have their default values from an API. The main idea is an Edit screen where the user can edit the details and then send them back. However, I cannot seem to get it working at all.
First, I get the data using an axios.get request:

```
      let { id } = useParams();
  const [unit, setUnit] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/units/${id}`).then((response) => {
    setUnit(response.data);
  });
}, []);
```

Then I assign the value I want to a state:

```
const [name, setName] = useState(unit.name);
```

Finally, I try to set it as the value (since I read that defaultValue cannot be controlled):

```
<TextField
            required
            label="Unit Name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(event) => {setName(event.target.value)}}
            fullWidth
            variant="outlined"
          />
```

However, the field does not contain any value. I tried assigning unit.name to a normal const and assign it to the textfield value and it worked but I could not edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution is setting the name after receiving the Axios request with the data:

```
setName(response.data.name)
```

Then set it as the value and using the onChange normally

```
<TextField
 required
 label="Unit Name"
 value={name}
 onChange={(event) => {setName(event.target.value)}}
 fullWidth
 variant="outlined"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you could change the value to the default value and then you could edit it.

```js
<TextField
 required
 label="Unit Name"
 defaultValue={name}
 onChange={(event) => {setName(event.target.value)}}
 fullWidth
 variant="outlined"
 />
```

Comment: Not working. Tried it before, but as I mentioned, defaultValue cannot be controlled

Answer (score 0):

I am running into a similar issue, I am first getting the data on the main component and the passing the entire value to the edit modal, it works fine as long as there is a value, but if any of the value's are null it will essentially crash

for Editing, I just have a new form state in the modal component, and on Change pass that to the form state.

Comment: How about initializing the value with an empty string rather than keeping it as null/undefined